# Attacks on RSA without knowledge of either key

Tags: encryption, attacks, rsa, attack-prevention

All attacks on RSA seem to require knowledge of at least the ciphertext and the public key.

However, has there ever been any evidence of an attack which simply uses a sufficiently large number of ciphertext to calculate the public *and / or* private key, and if so what is the recommended way to mitigate this?

Comment: What makes you think such an attack would be possible? Also public keys are generally something you already have. They're called "public" for a reason.

Comment: I remember how the attack on WEP worked, in that it was collect as much ciphertext as possible to discover the initialisation vector.  That and my limited knowledge in this area leads me to believe *such an attack on RSA may have been attempted before*.  I'd love to find out that it's somehow (verifiably) impossible though.

Comment: In theory weak key generation could be exploited using cipher texts only. Never done it myself but the NSA probably have :)

Comment: Think about it. RSA encryption is _c ≡ m^e (mod n)_ and RSA decryption is _m ≡ c^d (mod n)_. The public key contains _e_ and _n_, and the private key contains _d_ and _n_ (with _d_ being the modular inverse of _e_). An attack against RSA would require factoring _n_, which makes it possible to calculate _d_. Even if you can factor large semiprimes, how would you get _d_ without _n_? Also, see [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/55832/54184).

Comment: @forest - From that answer `Therefore, an attacker able to break the cryptosystem with the public key can obtain it under the usual assumption of a few known plaintext/ciphertext pairs, then break the cryptosystem.`.  This would tell me **it is** possible?

Comment: It tells you "maybe". Simply having a large number of ciphertexts does not help you, and getting known plaintext/ciphertext pairs is a little more difficult in RSA than in symmetric cryptosystems because the plaintext is usually a randomly-generated session key.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone has ever demonstrated finding the entire public key—all (say) 2048 bits of *n*—but [cryptographers demonstrated *distinguishing* public keys](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/728) ([popular exposition](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2014/10/29/attack-of-week-unpicking-plaid/)) by solving the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) on ciphertexts to break the privacy claims of PLAID, the Protocol for Lightweight Authentication of IDentity developed by the Australian Department of Human Services.

The basic idea of PLAID is an identification protocol for smart cards:  When you put your smart card into a legitimate hospital terminal, the terminal proves to the smart card that it represents legitimate hospital, and the smart card identifies you to the terminal, and then the terminal dispenses health care at you like a vending machine.

PLAID is intended to provide *privacy* from malicious terminals:  If you put your smart card into a malicious terminal which cannot prove to your smart card that it represents a legitimate hospital, the terminal should be unable to distinguish your card from any other card.

However, in the protocol, the smart card sometimes reveals RSA ciphertexts under a public key *n* stored on the smart card—even to illegitimate terminals.  **Every ciphertext under the key *n* is a nonnegative integer *c* < *n*, but since *n* is different for each key, the upper bound on ciphertexts is different for each key.**

Specifically, a malicious terminal can use the same methods used by British statisticians during World War II to estimate the number of German tanks by examining the serial numbers *c* of captured tanks which are all less than the total number *n* of tanks.  **The granularity of this estimate turns out to be enough to distinguish two smart cards' public keys simply by examining a sufficient number of ciphertexts made by them.**

Not all public-key cryptosystems have this property—for example, most public-key encryption and signature schemes that rely on the difficulty of computing discrete logs in a single standard group, like X25519 or Ed25519, tend to naturally provide the various related notions of [key privacy for public-key encryption](https://iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480568.pdf), [anonymous signatures](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11745853_23), or [key indistinguishability for signatures](https://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-01440-6_9) ([paywall-free](https://sci-hub.se/https://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-01440-6_9)).